# Compressing image in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express to serve resized images. Which Node.js package should be used to resize the image? I've seen a lot of packages that change the image and save it as a file, but I need to change the image and write data to response. Example:

```
package.compress('/path/to/image.png', 
    {width: 100px, height: 100px}, 
    function(result) {
        res.end(result);
});
```

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to compress the image when serving it to the client. I use [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) which gzip's the resources when serving them, though this is not optimal for images since there are more advanced optimization techniques applicable (like [imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin)). I'm not sure you would want to use that when serving, since it's a demanding operation (it can take seconds or even minutes for a single image). What is your use case?

Comment: @razvan I want to show image-preview to users. But previews should be generated when the query without saving.

Comment: Then you should have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chosen thumb-express (https://www.npmjs.com/package/thumb-express). This is what I need.